# strip spaces in python

Tags: python, string

ok I know that this should be simple... anyways say:

```
line = "$W5M5A,100527,142500,730301c44892fd1c,2,686.5  4,333.96,0,0,28.6,123,75,-0.4,1.4*49"
```

I want to strip out the spaces. I thought you would just do this

```
line = line.strip()
```

but now line is still '$W5M5A,100527,142500,730301c44892fd1c,2,686.5  4,333.96,0,0,28.6,123,75,-0.4,1.4*49' instead of '$W5M5A,100527,142500,730301c44892fd1c,2,686.54,333.96,0,0,28.6,123,75,-0.4,1.4*49'

any thoughts?

Comment: `strip` only removes spaces from the beginning or the end of the string. Also, how about going back to your old questions and marking good answers as accepted answers?

Comment: I just did, I am new to stackoverflow, thx for reminding me of my duties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
line = line.replace(' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing it

```
line = ''.join(line.split())
```